# Steps to Pass parameters to crystal reports in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

Can you tell me what are the steps to pass parameters to crystal reports 13 in C# win form..

my code:

```
        //getting and set dataset to report   
        string sql = "select * from dbo.Trading_Order";
        DataRetriever dr = new DataRetriever();
        dr.getValueFromCustomer(sql);
        DataTable dtSum = dr.getDataTable();
        dsMyReprt k = new dsMyReprt();
        k.Tables.Remove("dtMyTable");
        dtSum.TableName = "dtMyTable";
        k.Tables.Add(dtSum);
        CrystalReport1 myDataReport = new CrystalReport1();

        //pass parameter

        ParameterFields paramFields = new ParameterFields();
        // ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

        ParameterField paramField = new ParameterField();
        ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        paramField.Name = "@DTotal";
        paramDiscreteValue.Value = tot;
        paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
        paramFields.Add(paramField);

        paramField = new ParameterField(); 
        paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue(); 
        paramField.Name = "@name";
        paramDiscreteValue.Value = name;
        paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
        paramFields.Add(paramField);

        crystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;

        myDataReport.SetDataSource(k);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myDataReport;
```

getting and set dataset part is working
but passing parameters part is not working

Comment: What isn't working about it? What have you tried?

Comment: gleng : Working means, I hv added that my dataset table columns to my crystal report and it will display when in load. 
but after I tried to pass that parameter there is an error "The Parameter is incorrect"..

Comment: Wasn't there a "SetParameterValue" method on the report object?

Comment: Do you mean this?
myDataReport.SetParameterValue("@Total", 120000);
myDataReport.SetParameterValue("@name", "Nipun");

I also tried this but there is same error call "The Parameter is incorrect"

Comment: Do I need to make any changes in CrystalReport1.rpt file?

Comment: Your code is very good just remove the @ in the name of your parameters, you have to put the name as is, I have checked your code and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

I got big headaches with that for weeks... I have to precise that I set a sql query in the Crystal Reports Designer. Thus, I didn't use a dataTable like you did, so you have to consider that.

Well, @campagnolo_1 suggested you :

```
ReportDocument myDataReport = new ReportDocument();
myDataReport.Load(@"C:\Reports\Report.rpt");

myDataReport.SetParameterValue("MyParameter1", "Hello1");
myDataReport.SetParameterValue("MyParameter2", "Hello2");
myDataReport.SetParameterValue("MyParameter3", "Hello3");
```

This is the short and sweet solution. But, following this, you have to make sure you have created `MyParameter1`, `MyParameter2` and `MyParameter3`of type String in the Crystal Reports Designer.

1. It's important to mention that you have to Load the report before setting your parameters with `SetParameterValue`.
2. If your parameter's name is `MyParameter1`, then don't add a `@` in front like this :

   myDataReport.SetParameterValue("@MyParameter1", "Hello1"); // Your program will crash.
3. If you got `The parameter is incorrect` then you should make sure the type of parameter value you gave is exactly the same as the parameter type. For example, if you have a parameter `StartDate` as type Date, then make sure the value you'll give is of type Date and has the right date format.

Also, you have talked about dynamic or static field. In your case, I think you enter values manually, then this is static field.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you 3 years later, I googled SetParameterValue crash and found out you are not supposed to put the @ in front of the parameter (point 2).  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You probably have figured the solution by now. But this may help. You enter values that are passed as a parameter.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/753879/Automatically-Setting-a-Parameter-from-a-Csharp-Va

Answer (score 0):

Why not try it this way and save yourself some coding?

```
ReportDocument myDataReport = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();
myDataReport.Load(@"C:\Reports\Report.rpt");

myDataReport.SetParameterValue("MyParameter1", "Hello1");
myDataReport.SetParameterValue("MyParameter2", "Hello2");
myDataReport.SetParameterValue("MyParameter3", "Hello3");
```

Comment: No.. It ask to enter values to parameter after I run the program..
Do I need to make any changes in CrystalReport1.rpt file?

Comment: You have to make sure that the parameter names are spelled exactly the way they are in the report.

Comment: Yeah its same.Do I need to change that value type to static or dynamic ? And do I need change any formula field?