# Why does my CR SetParameterValue seem to not work

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I have a small Winforms project. .NetFramework 4.5, CR 13.0.14. In a ReportForm:

```
public partial class ReportForm : Form
{
    private readonly string _batchNumber;

    public ReportForm(string batchNumber)
    {
        _batchNumber = batchNumber;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        APGreenSheets report = new APGreenSheets();
        DataSet data = AccountsPayableController.FillDataSet();
        report.SetDataSource(data);
        report.SetParameterValue("BatchRef", _batchNumber);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
        crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();

        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
}
```

In my CR report I have a Parameter Field “BatchRef” defined as a string.

My Record Selection Formula is: `{AP_HistoryHeader.strBatchRef} = {?BatchRef}`

When ReportForm loads (passing in the Batch Number reference) the report still prompts me before it will load. I can type it in manually and that will work. But I have Set the Parameter after I set the DataSource to avoid that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried moving the Setparameter() code after setting the ReportSource line?? Does it still prompt? 
Another option might be to check inthe report itself.. Right Click parameter in report -> Edit - > Under the Value Options panel you will see a couple of Prompt settings.. Make sure they are set to False.

Comment: Thanks @amazing, I checked my Parameter Field and they are set to False. Moving the SetParameter did not change the behavior. However, I did notice if I remove my Selection Formula, It does not prompt me when the report Loads.

Comment: and your record selection formula is in the report? not being passed through code?

Comment: Also where do you load the report?? report.Load(@"C:\Reports\Report.rpt");

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930121/steps-to-pass-parameters-to-crystal-reports-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Amazing, my record Selection is in the Report. Also, the line `APGreenSheets report = new APGreenSheets();` news up and initializes the report. The report is not external to this project so I don't need to do a Load() here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don Williams at SAP provided me the correct answer after a few other code checks:

Simply remove the line `crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();`

This did the trick. Apparently the refresh part wants to renew the passed Parameter. It turns out, I didn't need it to display the report in the first place.

Thanks to Don!

Comment: Good. Gets you through this problem onto another.. ;-)