# C# Crystal Report ExportToDisk - Missing Parameter Values

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Is there an easy way to find out which parameter values are missing?

Here's the code I'm using to loop through the document parameters to set them.

I've set a breakpoint @

```
SetReportParameterValue(document, order, param.ParameterFieldName, paramValue);
```

The paramValue is never null or empty

Here's a simplified version of the whole method.  There's actually several parameters in the report but like I said, there's never a null or empty value and I cannot see any parameters inside the main report that are missing from my switch statement.

```
            var base_doc_parameters = document.ParameterFields;

            foreach (ParameterField param in base_doc_parameters)
            {
                var paramName = param.ParameterFieldName;

                if (document.DataDefinition.ParameterFields[paramName].IsLinked())
                {
                    continue; /* Crystal will throw an exception if we try to set a linked parameter (a main report parameter used in a subreport) */
                }



                object paramValue = null;

                switch (paramName.ToUpper())
                {
                    case "PARAMNAME":
                        paramValue = "TEST";
                        break;
                    default:
                        continue;
                }

                SetReportParameterValue(document, order, param.ParameterFieldName, paramValue);
            }
```

Inside the SetReportParameterValue method:

```
doc.SetParameterValue(parameterName, parameterValue);
```

I feel like I've ran into this issue before but cannot remember what I did to fix it.  I get the feeling it has something to do with linked parameters but not sure what exactly to look at.

Comment: Try naming all the parameters you are passing. The exact same thing happened to me on calling a WPF method, and I was missing `, null` and VS was not telling me about it at design time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Steps to Pass parameters to crystal reports in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930121/steps-to-pass-parameters-to-crystal-reports-in-c-sharp)

Comment: The problem seems to be that more than one subreport is using the same parameter.  So if I take this particular parameter out of all subreports except for one, it works fine.  If I had it to more than one, it throws the exception.

Comment: The way it seems to be working is by changing the name in each subreport by just adding 1,2,3 etc to the end and linking those to the main report parameter.